# JavaScript error when working on remote IE8

Tags: bug, javascript

I'm experiencing JavaScript errors that make using StackOverflow difficult when I log from work (the only access to Internet is through remote server, on which IE8 is started). Because of this error I couldn't see formatting toolbar when asking new question on StackOverflow, and I wasn't able to format the code.

The toolbar is available by edit and here, on Meta.

The errors are:

> Meldung: Script error
>
> Zeile: 0
>
> Zeichen: 0
>
> Code: 0
>
> URI: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=ee8dc25807f6

Unfortunatelly, this is the only info I have. Either the script could not be loaded (but it's external, so it shouldn't mess with site itself) or it ended with errors (I can't see them anyway).

Comment: IE8 is the new IE6. Stack Exchange policy is to support only current and previous versions of major browsers meaning IE10 and IE9. While not yet explicitly unsupported, it means the developers are not testing changes with IE8 anymore. You really better upgrade to IE9. (assuming there's a good reason why not a real browser like Chrome)

Comment: Having choice I would never use IE in first line. I would use internet browser :)

Comment: Hmm... you might even be better off browsing from your mobile. :)

Comment: Browsing is not an issue but typing from touch screen... either I'm too old or not enough masochistic :)

Comment: 31 is definitely too old. :P